# jetty 6 rewrite handler not working web server

Tags: webserver, jetty, mod-rewrite

I cannot make rewrite handler to work on Jetty server 6.1.24. Here is my example in Scala:

```
val server = new Server(8080);

val contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
val rewriteHandler = new RewriteHandler();
rewriteHandler.setRewriteRequestURI(false);
rewriteHandler.setRewritePathInfo(false);
rewriteHandler.setOriginalPathAttribute("requestedPath")
rewriteHandler.addRewriteRule("/site1/test1","/site2/test2");
contexts.addHandler(rewriteHandler);

server.setHandler(contexts);
server.start();

.....
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RewriteHandler must wrap server handler. Try to replace:

```
contexts.addHandler(rewriteHandler);
```

with:

```
rewriteHandler.setHandler(contexts);
```